# how to log model custom error msg in sql database

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, error-logging, asp.net-core-middleware

1. Build a Web API named, "DeviceManager"
   a. Build a model for below details and continue from model[model first]

   ### Device model:

   i. DeviceId - with regular expression "[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{7}" with error message.

   ii. DeviceName - with regular expression "[A-Z, ], max 50 chars"with error message.

   iii. DeviceIP - with regular expression "std IPv4" with error message.

   iv. HostName - with regular expression "[A-Z, ], max 15 chars" with error message.

   b. Add CRUD operations for above model.

   ### CustomError model

   i. Id - as Primary Key

   ii. ErrorMessage

   iii. CreatedTime
2. Add logging mechanism using middleware exception handling to add each action, error and exception and error in DataBase.
3. Integrate Swagger

Comment: Use UseExceptionHandler check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0